# function in javascript not getting called SignalR

Tags: javascript, signalr, client, invoke

I have an MVC application which uses signalR for event . In my view I have 4 buttons login, open, refreshToken, Logout. In my view clieck event of all 3 buttons works i.e login, refreshToken & Logout but onClick of open button is not working.
below is my code for client side

```
  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#login').click(function () {
                // call the Login method on the hub
                var tokenRequestResponse = integrationServerHub.server
                    .login("localhost:1500", false, $('#username').val(), $('#password').val())
                    .done(processTokenRequestResponse);
                // clear the events text box
                $('#events').val('');
                $('#events').prepend("login.click" + "\n");
            });
            $('#refresh').click(function () {
                $('#events').prepend("refresh.click" + "\n");
                // call the Refresh method on the hub
                var tokenRequestResponse = integrationServerHub.server
                    .refreshToken($('#accessToken').val(), $('#refreshToken').val())
                    .done();
            });
            $('#logout').click(function () {
                $('#events').prepend("logout.click" + "\n");
                // call the Logout method on the hub
                integrationServerHub.server
                    .logout($('#accessToken').val())
                    .done(function (tokenRequestResponse) {
                });
            });
            $('#open').click(function () {
                $('#events').prepend("open.click" + "\n");
                //Call Set Sing on method on hub
                integrationServerHub.server.SetSignOnToCampaign($('#accessToken').val())
                    .done();
                $('#events').prepend("SignOn.click" + "\n");
            });
        });
```

I have SignOn method on hub. But when I click open button nothing happens. But other 3 button works as expected. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Is your method "SignOn" or "SetSignOnToCampaign"? Your code says one thing, your comment says another.

```
    $('#open').click(function () {
        $('#events').prepend("open.click" + "\n");
        //Call Set Sing on method on hub
        //integrationServerHub.server.SetSignOnToCampaign($('#accessToken').val())
        integrationServerHub.server.SignOn($('#accessToken').val())            
                .done();
        $('#events').prepend("SignOn.click" + "\n");
    });
```

I would also check that your camel-case is valid. Change your hub method to "signOn" or "setSignOnToCampaign", as well as updating your javascript to the same.

"Pass in a camel-case version of the method name on the Hub. **SignalR automatically makes this change** so that JavaScript code can conform to JavaScript conventions." - [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#how-to-call-server-methods-from-the-client)